# Maytag MGS5770adw burner doesn't spark when its own knob is turned, but does for the other three knobs

Tags: gas-stove

I have a Maytag oven/range MGS5770adw. One of the burners does not power the igniter for any of the four burners when its own knob is turned to ignite, but gas does flow as I can light with a match. If I use one of the other three knobs, all four burners spark and the faulty burner ignites once I also turn on its knob I have replaced the faulty sealed burner, which included a new igniter. However, the problem persists. Could it be the knob for that burner is not sending the spark signal, as none of the burners spark. Not sure what to check next or what to replace.

Comment: is that one knob somehow looser that the other knobs?

Comment: @jsotola Looseness of the knob is evidently not an issue: we are told that it turns the gas valve on successfully. The valve shaft then engages the hollow (keyed) ring of the igniter switch, and "ignite" is the very firsts position you hit after turning away from "off".  If the knob were loose, it wouldn't be turning on the gas.

Comment: I'm thinking that something is not engaging ... that would make the knob action feel different

Comment: But that's not how it works. The knob doesn't engage the switch directly. The knob engages the valve shaft, and then the valve shaft engages the switch. The OP says the gas is turning on when they turn the knob, and "ignite" is the first thing after "off". Knob looseness is not a factor.

Comment: I had a range that did the same thing, or at least similar.  One burner wouldn't ignite by itself, but for some reason you could turn the gas on that one, then turn any of the others to ignite, and both burners would fire.  I just lived with it.

Answer (score 0):

The switch that is paired with that burner’s gas valve has failed open, meaning it is not completing the circuit to power the ignition module when you turn the knob to “light”.

If your range isn’t too old, you should be able to purchase a replacement wiring harness consisting of the four switches, wire, and a connector as an assembled unit that you can swap out.

Example (not for your range): https://www.repairclinic.com/PartDetail/Spark-Ignition-Switch/316580615/1614900

In my experience the switches are not sold by themselves.